# Unable to bind map with complex key from spring boot yaml file using @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to unmarshal map with a complex key from spring yaml configuration file to java.util.Map using spring boot and **@ConfigurationProperties** annotation. There are lot of examples about maps with simple keys, like

```
map: 
  key: value
```

or even maps with a simple key and complex value, like

```
map:
  key: {firstPartOfComplexValue: alpha, secondPartOfComplexValue: beta}
```

I've tested both of above examples - works good.

Now I need a complex key in a map:

```
map:
  ? {firstPartOfAKey: someValue1, secondPartOfAKey: someValue2}: value
```

And the result of such unmarshalling is an empty map.
Could you please, advice me what I'm doing wrong
Thanks in advance

There is my code:

***application.yml***

```
custom:
  users:
    ? {firstPartOfAKey: hello, secondPartOfAKey: world} : tom
```

***bean to unmarshall***

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("custom")
  public class MyBean {
    private Map<Key, String> users = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Key, String> getUsers() {
      return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Map<Key, String> users) {
      this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return users.toString();
    }

    public static class Key {
      private String firstPartOfAKey;
      private String secondPartOfAKey;

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Key key = (Key) o;
        return Objects.equals(firstPartOfAKey, key.firstPartOfAKey) &&
                Objects.equals(secondPartOfAKey, key.secondPartOfAKey);
      }

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(firstPartOfAKey, secondPartOfAKey);
      }

      public String getFirstPartOfAKey() {
        return firstPartOfAKey;
      }

      public void setFirstPartOfAKey(String firstPartOfAKey) {
        this.firstPartOfAKey = firstPartOfAKey;
      }

      public String getSecondPartOfAKey() {
        return secondPartOfAKey;
      }

      public void setSecondPartOfAKey(String secondPartOfAKey) {
        this.secondPartOfAKey = secondPartOfAKey;
      }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
        return String.format("firsPartOfKey: '%s', secondPartOfKey: '%s'", firstPartOfAKey, secondPartOfAKey);
      }
    }
}
```

***java config*** (it's empty)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Config {
}
```

***unit test***

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Config.class})
public class TestProps {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Test
    public void testYamlPropsLoad() {
      System.out.println(myBean);
    }
}
```

Test prints '{}' for map with complex key only. Other maps (with simple keys) are working good.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the binding of your `MyBean` is not processed at all if your test is executed without any exception, usually there should be an exception like:

> Binding to target {} failed:
>
> Property: custom.null Value: {{firstPartOfAKey=hello,
>   secondPartOfAKey=world}=tom} Reason: Failed to convert property value
>   of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.MyBean$Key'
>   for property 'null'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.example.MyBean$Key': no
>   matching editors or conversion strategy found

Obviously the parser is not able to process complex keys and is interpreting the key `null` and value `{firstPartOfAKey=hello, secondPartOfAKey=world}=tom`.

Maybe you can find another way to process your config by implementing a [custom editor / converter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-conversion).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no any exception at all (even no any warning), just empty map. But when I swapped key and value (so key becomes String and value becomes complex type) in yaml file and MyBean everything works fine. Seems it's a bug in springboot. Yaml file was checked by online validator and it's correct. I'll try to workaround this by suggested custom editor / converter. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I don't know if it's a bug or if it's intended not to support complex keys and it's weird that there is no exeption in your case. Nevertheless, try to go with the custom  converters. :)